# Efficiently checking if a word matches patterns in set (Python)

Tags: python, glob

I have a set of many simple globbing patterns and whole words, like this:

```
s = set(['ALE', 'BREAD*', 'BREAKFAST*', 'BROTH' ...])
```

I also a large list of words. I want to check if each word in this list matches either a) a globbing pattern in the set or b) a word in the set.

If there were no globbing patterns, I would just do something like:

```
for word in words:
    if word in s:
        # do something
```

But since the set contains globbing patterns as well, it won't find a match if I want to match 'BREADY' to 'BREAD*'

The only way I can think of doing this would be to use a nested for loop to compare each word to each pattern in the set. Is there a way I can check if each word has a match in the set without comparing it with every element in the set?

Comment: You really want to match `BREA` and `BREADDDDDDDDD`?

Comment: Those are globbing patterns, not regular expressions..

Comment: Do you wish to only handle full word matches and prefix matches? Or are some of your glob patterns more complicated, e.g. "*EA*AST"

Comment: @WaleedKhan - in this case, yes. The set of patterns comes from the [RID](http://www.kovcomp.co.uk/wordstat/RID.html) and the list of words is a transcript of a comic strip. I want to lump words in the transcript into categories based on the RID, so if a character says "I WANT SOME BREADDDD" I still want it to find a match.

Comment: MartijnPieters thanks, will update post to reflect that. tom, Only full word matches and prefix matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the full strings you want to match against separately from the prefixes you want to match. For your prefixes, further partition them into sets of equal-length prefixes (i.e. one set of length-1 prefixes, one set of length-2 prefixes, etc.).

i.e.

```
fullstrings = set(["BREAKFAST", "LUNCH", "DINNER", ...])
prefixes_by_length = {} # dict of length -> prefix string
...
prefixes_by_length[4] = set(["CORN", "DESK", ...])
prefixes_by_length[5] = set(["BREAD", "TABLE", ...])
```

Full string match is simple - just check if `word in fullstrings`.

For prefixes, you would check each length separately, starting from length 1 to the max prefix length you want to match. For each length `n`, check if `word[:n] in prefixes_by_length[n]`.

This would be a lot of efficient than looping over all your prefixes every time, if you have a lot of them.

```
for word in words:
    if word in fullstrings:
        "Match! do something"
    for n in prefixes_by_length:
        if word[:n] in prefixes_by_length[n]:
            "Match! do something"
```

Answer (score 1):

Granted the OP didn't want to loop around.

```
import re
import fnmatch
s = set(['ALE', 'BREAD*', 'BREAKFAST*', 'BROTH'])
patterns = [re.compile(fnmatch.translate(p)) for p in s]

for word in "BEING PALE I LIKE ALE WITH BREADDY ABROTH FOR BREAKFASTY TREATS AND BROTH".split():
    for pattern in patterns:
        if pattern.match(word):
            print "HIT", word
```

Gives:

```
HIT ALE
HIT BREADDY
HIT BREAKFASTY
HIT BROTH
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a wordlist `words`, and a search list `searches`. For the simple examples you gave, the following should suffice.

```
for word in words:
    for search in searches:
        if search[-1] == "*":
            search = search[:-1]
            if word.lower().startswith(search.lower()):
                yield word
        else:
            if word.lower() == search.lower():
                yield word
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I was trying to avoid looping over all prefixes every time I check a word. Post updated to reflect that.